# Rails and memcached in a logged env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

I see a lots of how to about rails and memcached.
But I cannot find an updated how to that teach how to use memcached in a site where there is both a public section and a logged users section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have gone through all of the [relevant Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/tags/18) and the official [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html), you should check out the [Scaling Rails](http://railslab.newrelic.com/scaling-rails) series.

Your public pages will likely not have any dynamic (user dependent) context, so page caching is good there.  The user dependent pages get a little tricky and require fragment caching or a mixture of page/action caching with ajax calls to get the user dependent content.

[Here is a basic example.](http://www.arailsdemo.com/posts/17)